# Valgrind complains "definitely lost of memory" when "new" & "delete" not in the same function

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am getting this error in valgrind report.

> ==31766== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 825

My code looks like:

```
struct FooList {
  FooList() {}
  FooList(const vector<Foo*>& fooList_): fooList(fooList_) {}
  ~FooList() {
      BOOST_FOREACH(Foo* fooPtr, fooList) {
        delete fooPtr;
      }
  }  
  vector<Foo*> fooList;
}

Foo* createFoo(bool flag)
{
  if(flag) return new FooDerivedA();
  else     return new FooDerivedB();
}

void main() 
{
  FooList fl;

  Foo* fooA = createFoo(true);
  // some manipulation on fooA, if an exception happens at this point, the memory leaks.
  fl.fooList.push_back(fooA);

  Foo* fooB = createFoo(false);
  // some manipulation on fooB, if an exception happens at this point, the memory leaks.
  fl.fooList.push_back(fooB);

  // fl's desctructor will release memory for all elements.
}
```

I am not sure if it's because the `new` and `delete` statement are not in the same function which causes the `definitely lost`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `Foo` have a virtual destructor?

Comment: It's: ~Foo() {}. How should I fix it?

Comment: there should be compile error, `FooList ` does not have default constructor.

Comment: You need `virtual ~Foo() {}`.

Comment: "which causes the definitely lost" - don't make wild assumptions.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: "I'm not sure if it's [...] which causes the definitely lost" - there's no assumption there, just an expression of doubt.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: let's clean this up.